# Estimate power law exponent for node degree distribution in scale free networks

Tags: python, power-law

I am trying to use the `powerlaw` python package to estimate the power law exponent of the degree distribution in a graph. As a reference I am using `networkx` to generate a scale free network graph which should have an exponent close to 3. This is my code:

```
import powerlaw
import networkx as nx
g = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(1000, 5)
degrees = {}
for node in g.nodes_iter():
    key = len(g.neighbors(node))
    degrees[key] = degrees.get(key, 0) + 1

max_degree = max(degrees.keys(), key=int)
num_nodes = []
for i in range(1, max_degree + 1):
    num_nodes.append(degrees.get(i, 0))

fit = powerlaw.Fit(nodes)
print(fit.power_law.alpha)
```

The code above creates a scale free network with minimum node degree of five. I would expect the `powerlaw` package to find `xmin` to be >5 and to correctly estimate `alpha`. but it returns something around 1.8 instead of 3.0 for `alpha` and places `xmin` at 1 or 2. Is my data format wrong, or do I have to specify some other parameters?

Comment: Questions solely about how software / code works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it is still of interest, however, you are estimating the exponent of the CDF of the degree which is equal to $-\alpha+1$, where $\alpha$ is 3 for the Barabasi Albert model, therefore, you should add +1 to your estimation which indeed gains something close to 3 as expected.

Comment: Is the exponent of the CCDF also −+1 ?